# Error 500 after auth on redirect https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/access_token?client_id=183536378401103&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/

Tags: facebook, oauth, confirm

GoodMorning

after auth confirm my app doesn't work.

There is an arror 500 on https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/access_token?client_id=183536378401103&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/barometrorischio/home.php

until a few weeks ago the app worked perfectly.

below the code of my index

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'  => APP_ID,
                   secret' => SECRET,
                       'cookie' => false));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) { 
try {
// Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
$user = null;
  }
}


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Il Barometro del Rischio</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php            
            if (isset($user) && $user != 0) {
                $redirect = "https://apps.facebook.com/".APP_NAME."/home.php";            
            }   else    {
                $uri="https://apps.facebook.com/".APP_NAME."/home.php";
                $redirect = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/access_token?client_id=".APP_ID."&redirect_uri=".$uri;
            }
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">window.open('<?=$redirect?>', '_parent', '');</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't know what happen.

I Have another app with the same code in Index e it work pefectly

can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

you are doing something wrong

change

```
        $redirect = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/access_token?client_id=".APP_ID."&redirect_uri=".$uri;
```

to

```
    $redirect = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=".APP_ID."&redirect_uri=".$uri;
```